# How to get second findLibrary in maps

Tags: c++

```
06200000-0620d000 r--p 00000000 08:06 1009                  /system/lib/arm/libbase.so -- not here
0620d000-0620e000 r--p 0000c000 08:06 1009                 /system/lib/arm/libbase.so  -- get here
0620e000-0620f000 rw-p 0000d000 08:06 1009                /system/lib/arm/libbase.so
```

how to get second Address in this case
using this code

```
DWORD findLibrary(const char *library) {
    char filename[0xFF] = {0},
            buffer[1024] = {0};
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    DWORD address = 0;

    sprintf(filename, OBFUSCATE("/proc/self/maps"));

    fp = fopen(filename, OBFUSCATE("rt"));
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror(OBFUSCATE("fopen"));
        goto done;
    }

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) {
        if (strstr(buffer, library)) {
            address = (DWORD) strtoul(buffer, NULL, 16);
            goto done;
        }
    }

    done:

    if (fp) {
        fclose(fp);
    }

    return address;
}
```

This code only takes the first line, I want to take the second or third line

Comment: ... Keep a counter for the number of times you saw `library`?

Comment: Try this:  `uint32_t start_addr, end_addr; fscanf(fp, "%x-%x", &start_addr, end_addr);`  Keep the format specifier regardless of which `scanf` you are using.

Comment: Challenge:  can you rewrite this without using `goto`?  (Hint: try another level of loops)